# How to change a TextBlock's visibility based on a property's value

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatrigger

I've managed to get the TreeView working in a WPF app.  I'm using HierarchialDataTemplates to display the data.  My data is a list of Vehicles, where each Vehicle has a Territory property.

Sometimes the Territory property is Null.  This happens when the Vehicle has not been assigned to a geographic region.

The visual representation that I would like in the TreeView should be something like this:

> Vehicle_Name **(Territory_Name)**

When Vehicle.Territory is Null I'd like the **bold** text to be removed.  If it remains there's this weird empty parentheses at the end of the Vehicle name.

I've tried using a DataTrigger, but the bold text remains, even for null Territory values.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:TreeVehicleItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientLocations}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="10 0 0 0">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Territory}" Value="x:Null">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        (<Run Text="{Binding Territory.Name}" />)
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I've verified that the `Territory` property is indeed `Null` and not just an empty List.

What do I need to do to make the bold TextBlock disappear when the Territory property is Null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the string `"x:Null"`

```
 Value="x:Null"
```

This is the [markup extension `NullExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.nullextension(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns an actual `null`. This is what you want.

```
 Value="{x:Null}"
```

Comment: * head slap *  Thank you so much Ed!